# How to find an encryption algorithm between two hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: encryption, hash, salt, algorithm

I have several numbers that are generated by a server. They are 16 digits long and are hexadecimal. I have no idea whether or not any salting or hashing techniques were used. Can I find the encryption algorithm(s) used and/or if any salting was used? Thanx in advance.
Examples:
1c7a62331ff7410c
e3b9050cfa584ef0
e5c8996065f443b6
e0d4033494ed4d5f

Comment: Your title doesn't fit the content of your question. Could you clarify the "between two"?

Comment: This type of question is off topic here - mostly for the reason described by @mti2935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern encryption algorithms are designed such that the ciphertext is indistinguishable from random noise.  But if an older algorithm was used, it may be possible to glean some information about the algorithm from the ciphertext.  [See this post on Cryptography SE for more info.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-it-possible-to-derive-the-encryption-method-from-encrypted-text)